# indexDB is not persisting in SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, safari, sfsafariviewcontroller

Given the script:

```
function test() {
  let req = window.indexedDB.open("testingdb", 1);

  req.onupgradeneeded = evt => {
    let db = evt.target.result;
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains("keys")) {
      db.createObjectStore("keys", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
    }
  };

  req.onsuccess = evt => {
    let db = evt.target.result;
    let tx = db.transaction("keys", "readwrite");
    let st = tx.objectStore("keys");
    let dataReq = st.getAll();
    dataReq.onsuccess = dataEvt => {
      if (dataEvt.target.result.length === 0) {
        alert("new db");
        st.add({ test: 1 });
      } else {
        alert("old db");
      }
      db.close();
    };
  };
}
```

If I run it on page load in Safari on iOS 12, first load I get the alert "new db", every subsequent load I get "old db". I can quit Safari, restart the phone, etc and still get "old db".

If I use [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) first load gives me "new db", reload gives me "old db". BUT if I click done the db is wiped and subsequent [init](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller/1621222-init) will give me "new db" so indexDB is simply not persisted between sessions. Cookies are, local storage is. Per:

```
  if (localStorage.getItem("testing")) {
    alert("old local storage");
  } else {
    alert("new local storage");
    localStorage.setItem("testing", "yay");
  }
```

Are there any workaround here to this bug? Can the bug be feature detected without exiting and entering SFViewController

Comment: Opened #46651800  on apple bugreport